# Populating a DropDown with Excel Special Keys for Dynamic Shortcut Assignment

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, keyboard, vba

I am designing a GUI to allow users to assign shortcut keys to macro functions from a UserForm in Microsoft Excel.  The form performs exactly as intended, but in order to assign keys I use an InputBox to fetch data from the user.

However, the user cannot enter special keys (like Del, F1-F12, Home, End, etc.) into an InputBox.  I wanted to populate a DropDown with all of the regular AND special keys that Excel recognizes as viable shortcuts.

Is there a library object or default array which I can reference to populate my DropDown menu or will I have to find a list and add each item to an array manually?

[image]

Comment: If you are merely using the shortcuts which can be assigned through the GUI (Developer-Tab --> Macros --> select a macro --> press options...) then there is only the alphabet in combination with `Ctrl` and no special keys allowed. If you want to capture the `SendKeys` to start a macro then you can even assign predefined keys to carry out completely new and unexpected tasks (such as `F1` to quit Excel for example). If you want to know which keys are already in use on a computer then you'll have to check Windows, Excel, and also for running programs like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: I am using the Application.OnKey property to assign the shortcut for Excel only.  I am not capturing SendKeys.  What I need is a way to dynamically assign keys like [Del] and [F11] to a string variable without forcing the user to physically type the characters [, D,E,L, and ].  I had thought a dropdown, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the KeyDown event on a TextBox to capture the user's input. Put a label to the left of a textbox and use code like this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    Dim dcText As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dcText = New Scripting.Dictionary

    If Shift And 2 Then dcText.Add "Ctrl", 2
    If Shift And 4 Then dcText.Add "Alt", 4
    If Shift And 1 Then dcText.Add "Shift", 1

    Me.Label1.Caption = Join(dcText.Keys, "+") & "+"
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Chr$(KeyCode)

End Sub
```

That code needs a little work (like to limit the options), but it should get you started.

Comment: This sounds very much like what I need.  I don't think I need all of that Dictionary stuff, as I have buttons that modify the label directly to represent modifier keys.  One issue: When I set the inputbox text using Chr$, two things happen.  If it is a letter key, it double-types it: Press j -> "Jj".  But if I press a special key, it produces a random character.  Press [Del] -> '.', for example.

Comment: The actual KeyDown should put a letter in the box making the Chr$ part unnecessary. But it wasn't happening for me, so I fudged it then put "this code needs work" to excuse my bad code. Press Ctrl+K: When you press Ctrl, the Shift argument becomes 2 and the KeyCode argument is the code for Ctrl (like 16 or something). Then when you press K, Shift stays at 2 because it's specifically looking at Shift, Ctrl, and Alt, but KeyCode goes to the code for K. So for that little bit where you have Ctrl pressed but not K, KeyCode is not what you expect.  You might try KeyUp to elimiate that problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the Chr$ only works for normal characters.  Keys like Del and Home and F2 do not display correctly.  I've managed a decent workaround though by doing a Select Case on each of the special characters.  I like this result better than using a dropdown because my users can just type without having to scan a list with their eyes.

Comment: Well if you get something useful worked out, consider updating your question with the final code. I wouldn't mind having that in my code library.